# Restoring Silicon Mac in enterprise environment

Tags: restore, certificate, proxy, ipsw

Is there some way to do a full IPSW restore in an enterprise environment?

In our case this means no DHCP and behind a proxy. Other machines all have a fixed IP and proxy certificate installed. But last time I tried this won't work with a Silicon Mac because it wants to fetch some stuff from Apple before you even get to the point where you can install certificates.

Or is there maybe some way to auto-deploy them during a restore?

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done from another Mac running the latest version of [Apple Configurator 2 (US link)](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12&uo=4).

Configurator can actually download the latest IPSW for you, or you can manually drag a local .IPSW file into the Restore window.

The always reliable Mr Macintosh has a [great write-up on the process](https://mrmacintosh.com/How-to-Reinstall-macOS-on-your-Apple-Silicon-Mac-Everything-you-Need-to-Know/).

Comment: The problem is not downloading the IPSW or getting into full restore mode to some extend. But during restore MacOS likes to fetch some stuff but it does so before you can install any certificate. Since there is then a conflict during the TLS connection it will abort.

Answer (score 0):

No, in that environment it cannot be done as far as I know. Those checks will have to go through in order for you to be able to actually boot the system afterwards.

This type of system is, amongst other things, what makes it possible to register an Apple-silicon Mac as stolen with Apple and then be able to prevent the thief not knowing a user password from reinstalling it to be able to actually get it usable again.